# how to get the keys according to parent and child using angular

Tags: javascript, json

here I have an array of objects like

```
[{
    "id": "company",
    "checked": true,
    "model": true,
    "maker": true,
    "country": true,
    "enterprise": true
  },
  {
    "id": "config",
    "checked": true,
    "ram": true,
    "processor": true,
    "hdd": true
  }
]
```

When I try to grab the object keys here what is expected is:

**expected output**

```
["company", "checked", "model", "maker", "country", "enterprise"]
```

**what I am getting is:**

```
["id", "checked", "model", "maker", "country", "enterprise"]
```

So how can I get the value of the id & rest of the keys?

Comment: "when i try to grab the object values" --> how are you doing this? Please show your code.

Comment: Basically the requirement is confusing, either you can have an array of keys from object or its values as array. But if you need to have a mix of both then you need to iterate with keys and if the key is id or something, you have to take its value and push it to an array.

Comment: @PadmapriyaVishnuvardhan in the every object i have to get the id /key value later then  i have to get the all key names

Comment: Added the code snippet as my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```js
var yourArray = [{
    "id": "company",
    "checked": true,
    "model": true,
    "maker": true,
    "country": true,
    "enterprise": true
  },
  {
    "id": "config",
    "checked": true,
    "ram": true,
    "processor": true,
    "hdd": true
  }
];

var expectedResponse = yourArray.map(obj => {
  var yourExpectedArray = Object.keys(obj);
  var indexOfId = yourExpectedArray.indexOf('id');
  yourExpectedArray[indexOfId] = obj['id'];
  return yourExpectedArray;
});

console.log(expectedResponse);
```

Comment: can i get the output as company as key and all rest under the company like object key

Comment: Yes you are going to get exactly that with this. Please check it by clicking on the *Run Code Snippet* button.

Comment: what i mean is like comany {prop1,prop2,prop3 } like this so that i can set the fields as company.prop1 if it have child other wise just company

Answer (score 1):

Map over the entries and if the value is boolean return the key otherwise return the value

```js
const all = [{
    "id": "company",
    "checked": true,
    "model": true,
    "maker": true,
    "country": true,
    "enterprise": true
  },
  {
    "id": "config",
    "checked": true,
    "ram": true,
    "processor": true,
    "hdd": true
  }
]

const data = all.map(props =>
  Object.entries(props).map(([key, value]) =>
    typeof value === "boolean" ? key : value
  )
);

console.log(data)
```

Comment: it is giving Object Constructor error & can i get the output as company as key and all rest under the company like object key

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var jsonArr = [{
    "id": "company",
    "checked": true,
    "model": true,
    "maker": true,
    "country": true,
    "enterprise": true
  },
  {
    "id": "config",
    "checked": true,
    "ram": true,
    "processor": true,
    "hdd": true
  }
];

const result = jsonArr.map((item, index) => {
  const keys = Object.keys(item);
  keys[0] = item[keys[0]];
  return keys;
});

console.log(result);
```

I'm assuming that `id` is going to be always the first `key` in the Object in the Array.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var jsonArr = [{
    "id": "company",
    "checked": true,
    "model": true,
    "maker": true,
    "country": true,
    "enterprise": true
  },
  {
    "id": "config",
    "checked": true,
    "ram": true,
    "processor": true,
    "hdd": true
  }
];

const result = jsonArr.map((item, index) => {
  const keys = Object.keys(item);
  keys.filter((key, keyIndex) => {
      //console.log(key);
      if(key === "id") {
          keys[keyIndex] = item[key];
      }
  });
  
  return keys;
});

console.log(result);
```

This will help you to find any key at any place.